# combine bin and install script

Tags: node.js, package.json

Given the following excerpt from package.json:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Foo",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "bin": "bin/index-cli.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "install": "tsc",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  ...
}
```

`npm install` fails with:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/mk/work/my-project/node_modules/foo/bin/index-cli.js'
```

Which is, because the install script (tsc - typescript compiler), which generates bin/index-cli.js from src/index-cli.ts is not executed before npm tries to create the sym link.

**Question:** What is the right way to have a bin, which is generated by an install script?